# Change the update location of a vsto add-in with click once

Tags: c#, deployment

I've published a Word add-in to location X. I want to move the installation to location Y without losing the ClickOnce update functionality and without asking my users to reinstall the add-in. Ive made some research but couldn't find any concrete answer.

Has someone encountered this issue? If so, how can I do it?